# Paypal billing circles for recurring payment

Tags: paypal, membership, subscription, recurring

I created a Paypal subscription button. But I see that the number of billing circles is limited by 30 circles. But I need to create 60 circles or 120 circles. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

While you are correct the PayPal Standard Subscription buttons has a limit of 30 Cycles (or unlimited if no limit given), Express Checkout Recurring Billing will allow you to have 120 cycles.

[Express Checkout Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/)

From the PayPal Documentation on [Express Checkout Recurring](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/) you will send the below in your CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile call include :

```
&METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
TOKEN=EC-13W99099UU817504D
&PROFILESTARTDATE:20XX-03-05T03:00:00
&DESC=Movie clips
&BILLINGPERIOD=Month
&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1
&TOTALBILLINGCYCLES=120
&AMT=1.00
&CURRENCYCODE=USD
&EMAIL=payername@bbb.net
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Kitty Antics
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=1.00
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
```

You will also need to have a working Express Checkout setup, here is a link to the [PayPal Integration Wizard Sample Code](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/code.php).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But If I would my customer recurring for 5 years,pay every month so I should set total billing cycles for 59 or 60 cycles?

Comment: That is correct, I was only using your example of 120 cycles, but for 5 years it is 60 cycles if you are billing monthly. For 10 years it is 120 cycles.

Comment: One more thing that I called DoExpressCheckoutPayment to return transaction ID but it charge buyer two time. How can I get transaction ID without call DoExpressCheckoutPayment or call it but still charge one time? Thanks you again.

Comment: You can either use [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) or [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_searchRetrieveTransactionData-curl-etc/)